# xamarin load web page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to load a web page into a xamarin app my mainactivity.cs page has the following code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView webView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        webView.LoadUrl("https://urlofwebpage");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
        webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

and my main.axml contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

it seems to build but I only ever get a black screen in the emulator

Can anyone shed some light on why?

Comment: what device are you using in the emulator? try phones if trying with tablets

Comment: It's an android app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for your code:

```cs
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
    webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

The `true` value is not set to the `webView.Settings`, it is set to the variable `webSettings`, they're different object. To enable `JavaScriptEnabled` of your `WebView`, directly code like this:

```cs
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

I noticed that your url is like `https://urlofwebpage`, for ssl connection, you can create a `WebViewClient` for your `WebView`, and then override the `OnReceivedSslError` to check the error message, for example:

```cs
webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

`MyWebViewClient` is like this:

```cs
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
    {
        base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        switch (error.PrimaryError)
        {
            case SslErrorType.Untrusted:
                //TODO:
                break;

            case SslErrorType.Expired:
                //TODO:
                break;

            case SslErrorType.Idmismatch:
                //TODO:
                break;

            case SslErrorType.Notyetvalid:
                //TODO:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've followed a couple of tutorials this one 
  
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/load_a_web_page/      and this one                     
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwWOAWmNMXQ and it seems correct the way it is